# Ubuntu Flickering While Installing & Booting

Tags: boot, drivers, dell, intel-graphics, flicker

I am an ubuntu user. I installed Ubuntu a few months ago. It worked properly for me. But after about 1 week later, it randomly started flickering while booting, it almost flickered for 10 minutes and i finally reached in login screen. The login screen and desktop has don't any flickering issues, but it happened only while booting. But after few days it flickered forever while booting, I uninstalled Ubuntu and tried to reinstall. But it also flickered forever while installing through USB.I changed my boot to legacy and UEFI, But i cant find any solution. I dont use any OS except Ubuntu that time. Now I am struggling to install Ubuntu. ***Pls Help Me To Fix It!***

This was the similar problem I had: https://youtu.be/S-S1PGlfhdw
Reminder: I only used Ubuntu, there were no other OS

Specification:
Dell Inspiron 3542
Intel HD Graphics
4gb Ram

Comment: It is likely a hardware problem not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: How Do I Fix That?

Comment: Repair the hardware or buy new.